# Java List<MyClass> to TreeMap<Long, MyClass>

Tags: java, list, treemap

is there any way, how to convert `List<MyClass>` to `TreeMap<Long, MyClass>` with **reasonable** performance? I have found method `Maps.uniqueIndex()` in Google Collections, but it return only `Map`.

List can be destroyed during process of conversion, I need just TreeMap. I use TreeMap because i need fast search and indexation with long.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As the operations `put`, `get`, `remove` (and others) of class `TreeMap` have time complexity O(log n), you will always end with a time complexity of O(n log n) for any conversion algorithm. Using a `HashMap` is much better, if you want "fast search".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simpler method than iteration.

```
Map<Long, MyClass> tree = new HashMap<Long, MyClass>();
for (MyClass cl: classList){
   tree.put(cl.getId(), cl);
}
```

Just like Seelenvirtuose mentioned:
If you want search performance: HashMap, if you want your elements to be sorted use TreeMap.
In search performance goes to HashMap.

Comment: Time complexity of this simple iteration _is not_ O(n), it is O(n log n). The iteration itself is obvioiusly O(n), but you forgot to consider that `TreeMap.put` has time complexity O(log n). Together it is O(n log n).

Comment: And as the OP requested "fast search and indexation", you should also consider proposing to use `HashMap` instead of `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

In **Java 8** use Stream API for the most simple way:

```
Map<Long, MyClass> map = myClassList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass::getId, c -> c));
```

As you care for efficency, you should use `HashMap` instead of `TreeMap`. Specifying the implementation of `Map` looks like this:

```
Map<Long, MyClass> map = myClassList.stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new, (map, myClass) -> map.put(myClass.getId(), myClass), HashMap::putAll);
```